# Rails: Whats the easiest method to convert a serialized hash column into json column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a legacy column in a postgresql db thats a serialized hash and I want to convert it to a json data type.  I'm pretty sure that I can't just do a migration and convert it to a json.  Please tell me the easiest method of creating a new column, copying the data from one column to another, deleting the old column and renaming the new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a json column acts much like a serialized column, keep in mind there are some circumstances where a json column can't be used a drop-in replacement (e.g.  with some extensions like ActiveAdmin). Therefore, I'd recommend keeping the original column, and non-destructively copying data to your new JSON column under a different name. Ensuring you can safely migrate data while being able to revert potential issues.

The process would look something like this:

1. Create migration to add a new JSON column. *Commit to git*
2. Write a rake task to iterate through each record (probably using `find_each`) and **copy** data from your existing serialized column to the newly created JSON column for each record. *Commit to git*
3. Replace references in your code to original serialized column with references to your new column. *Commit to git*
4. Run tests extensively, preferably on a staging server with existing data
5. Backup database and run Rake task on production

I highlight the "commit to git" step, especially in step 3 as it allows you to easily isolate/bisect/revert any potential errors. Also, if this is a true refactoring the external behavior of your app shouldn't change simply because you're using a JSON column vs. serialized column so you can revert step 3 & rerun tests to better verify this and isolate errors/changes. And if something goes wrong, you'll be able to get back to where you were since step 2 is non-destructive.

To eliminate downtime, you'll obviously want to run the migration and copy the data via the rake task before you deploy code changes in step 3.

Finally, once you're confident of the integrity of your data you can delete the original serialized column allowing you to rename the JSON column to the column's original name.

Comment: No problem, best of luck!

Comment: If it works for you, would you mind accepting the answer?